# AngularFire2 query not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

What I'm trying to achieve is to show some news from my database in an Angular app, and my problem is that I can't manage to query the database.
I am more than certain that it's just a small mistake, but for the sake of it I can't figure it out.

**Edit 1** - After implementing the code provided by @David East, i am only getting an error on the ".equalTo(category))" line, telling me that it's expecting a semicolon or ,}). At this point I'm stuck, and any help would be great.

Course.component

```
    export class CoursesListComponent implements OnInit {
  coursesObservable;
  categorySubject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public auth: AuthService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.coursesObservable = this.categorySubject.map(category => {
      return this.db.list<any[]>('courses', ref  => {
        return ref.orderByChild('category')
          .equalTo(category))
          .valueChanges();
    });
}
    pickCategory (category: string) {
      this.categorySubject.next(category);
    }

}
```

Html

```
  <ul>
  <div class="scrollmenu">
    <select [(ngModel)]="category" (change)="pickCategory(category)">
      <option *ngFor="let category of coursesObservable | async" value="{{category.title}}">{{ category.title }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let course of coursesObservable | async">

    <a href="{{course.url}}" target="_blank" >
      <h3>{{course.title}}</h3>
      <p>{{course.description}}</p>
       </a>

  </div>
</ul>
```

And the JSON file for firebase

```
{  "courses":
        {
          "Angular 1" : {
            "description" : "Lorem Ipsum",
            "title" : "Title 1",
            "url" : "https://www.news.ro/"
            "category" : "test"
          },
          "Angular 2" : {
            "description" : "Itent, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).",
            "title" : "Title 2",
            "url" : "https://www.news.ro/"
            "category" : "test"
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the async pipe to kick off an observable subscribe or otherwise nothing will happen.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="category" (change)="pickCategory(category)">
  <option *ngFor="let category of coursesObservable | async" value="{{category.title}}">{{ category.title }}</option>
</select>
```

For updating categories on change you need to change your pickCategory method to emit new values to change the query. This is easiest using an RxJS subject. You want to be able to rebuild the query whenever a user selects a new value. A subject will create a stream of category values. Whenever there is a new value you can instruct AngularFire to rebuild the query based on the new value.

```
Course.component.constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public auth: AuthService) { }
  categorySubject = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coursesObservable = this.categorySubject.map(category => {
      return this.db.list<any[]>('courses', ref  => {
        return ref.orderByChild('category')
                  .equalTo(category))
                  .valueChanges();
      });
    });
  }

  pickCategory (category: string) {
    this.categorySubject.next(category);
  }

}
```

This way AngularFire can rebuild the query whenever a new value is submitted.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. My only problem now is that i get ''Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'false'' on the .'equalTo(category))' line. What should I do ?

Comment: Until you know what type you need you can use this.db.list<any[]>. I've updated the answer.

Comment: that doesn't change anything at all. What exactly I am doing wrong? If you have the time and patience this is the [repository](https://github.com/incrosnatubogdan/Angular2FirebaseRSSTalker). Thank you a lot

Comment: Oh I see. You need to type new Subject<any>(); Ive updated the answer.

Comment: I still get an error telling me that I am missing something next to ".equalTo(category))", what exactly is it expecting there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you update the question with more details?